# Override join generated by Rails eager_load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a situation where I want to group certain records and `eager_load` the associations, so I created a view that is something like this:

```sql
select group id, array_agg(order_ids) order_ids
from my_table
group by 1
```

So it will have records like this:

```
id | order_ids
1  | {1, 2, 3}
2  | {4, 5}
```

Then I created a model for this view:

```rb
class MyGroup < ApplicationRecord
  scope :with_orders, -> {
    joins("JOIN orders on orders.id = any(order_ids)")
    .eager_load(orders: [:address, :products])
  }

  has_many :orders
end
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to remove or override the join that Rails generates for the `orders` relation, which is something like this:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN "orders" "orders_my_groups" ON "orders_my_groups"."my_group_id" = "my_groups"."id"
```

Is there some way to tell Rails to use a specific join instead of the one generated by the `has_many` association? Or is there any other kind of association I could use in this case?

What I want to do here is eager load all associations from a group in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on trying to override the Rails `eager_load` generated join and used a `has_many :through` relation:

Wrote a view like this for the grouping:

```sql
SELECT group_id, description FROM my_table GROUP BY group_id
```

And added this to the model that uses this view:

```rb
class MyGroup < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = "group_id"

  has_many :items, foreign_key: "group_id", class_name: "MyTable"
  has_many :orders, through: :items
end
```

Now rails just generates a SQL like this and `eager_load` works.

```
SELECT group_id, description from my_view
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table ON my_table.group_id = my_group.group_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't override eager_load joins. Instead you can get the data you are looking for using association itself.

Eager load while loading records

```
@groups = MyGroup.includes(orders: [:address, :products])
```

And the place you need the order_ids

```
@groups.each do |group|
  # ...
  order_ids = group.order_ids # returns array object
```

No need to use join again here. It will cause N+1.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your suggestion. I tried it and loads the orders but does an N+1, if I use `.joins(:orders)` I get a comparison error: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]`

Comment: Please share the full statement in which you get this error